# How to accelerate buffering of output string?

Tags: c#, windows-7, visual-studio-2012

This code times two methods of outputting a ~380Kb string:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string outbuff = "";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                Stopwatch exectime = new Stopwatch();
                System.IO.StreamWriter file;
                exectime.Reset(); exectime.Start();
                file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("output.html");
                for (int i = 0; i < 18000; i++)
                {
                    outbuff += "444444444, 5555555555\n";
                }
                string fin = "\nString method took " + exectime.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + "s";
                file.WriteLine(outbuff);
                Console.WriteLine(fin);
                file.WriteLine(fin);
                file.Close();
            }
            {
                Stopwatch exectime = new Stopwatch();
                System.IO.StreamWriter file;

                exectime.Reset(); exectime.Start();
                file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("output2.html");
                for (int i = 0; i < 18000; i++)
                {
                    file.Write("444444444, 5555555555\n");
                }
                string fin = "\nDirect method took " + exectime.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + "s";
                Console.WriteLine(fin);
                file.WriteLine(fin);
                file.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

String method took 2.2985349s
 Direct method took 0.07191s

This is on a 3.5GHz CPU with 5Gb RAM.

I'm disappointed that simply buffering the output in a string is so costly!

In my real program, I need to deferr output until the string is assembled. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead to assemble your string.

For an in-depth explanation for the performance boost see ["Using the StringBuilder Class"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - but basically because strings are immutable a new string is created when you concatenate, which is very expensive.

Comment: "StringBuilder method took 0.0018911s" Sorted! Thanks, BG. Though I must say (call me old-fashioned),  I thought such optimisation was the job of the compiler...

Comment: @ChrisJJ The compiler can do a lot of fun optimizations, but it has limits.  It comes down to the way that the `String` class is implemented, and it's done as a static buffer.  Changing the string usually requires a new buffer.  The `StringBuilder` class can pre-allocate a buffer, dynamically resize the buffer, etc. to do string operations *much* faster.

Comment: "Changing the string usually requires a new buffer." How terribly 20thC :) Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: +1. @ChrisJJ, Not sure which way you tried to joke about inability to modify "String" values... But if you ever tried to write correct multithreaded code that deals with potentially mutable strings you may consider immutable string really way of the future.